# Update a row with prepared statements OOP with PHP + Mysqli

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm trying to  a row in my 'users' table to activate their account.

```
if ( $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare(" users SET activated='1' WHERE activationCode=?") )      
{

    $stmt -> bind_param("s",$actvt );

    $stmt -> execute();

} else {

      echo $mysqli->error;

}
```

This doesn't seem to work, I just can't figure out how to do the `` ` statement, because ``SELECT` works everytime.

EDIT: I now refer to `$mysqli->error;` in the `else` statement, however, I mave no response whatsoever.

EDIT2: Read a comment, added `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` Now the error message states:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop-homepage\activate.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop-homepage\activate.php(26): mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users SE...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop-homepage\activate.php on line 26
```

Line 26 is line 1 in my example

Comment: First of all http://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/285587

Comment: Refer to `$mysqli->error`.

Comment: You're assuming that `$mysqli->prepare` fails, but it may be the call to `$stmt->execute`, that fails. Output `$mysqli->error` after that.

Comment: @Callidior Get rid of the if statment?